# How to get path of folder inside Emulator

Tags: android, kotlin, android-emulator

I added some folder inside Emulator's SD Card from File Explorer. However, I have been having a hard time locating this folder programmatically to access contents inside the directory. From the image below, say I want to get path to "BiometricImages" folder. How can I do so.

This approach I use does not work for me.

```
   val directory = appContext.getExternalFilesDir("BiometricImages")
```

`val images = Files.walk(Paths.get(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/BiometricImages"), 5).filter { it.absolutePathString().endsWith(".jpg") }.toList()`

I am using this code to access some contents inside the directory. The results recognizes that the directory is present but for a strange reason, it doesnt recognize the contents inside the directory. Always returns empty. However, it works on real device

[image: Emulator Image]

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). Then add your folder

Comment: And it is not on the emulators sd card.

Comment: I have tried that but I cannot access the contents of the folder. Do i need to add some permissions?

Comment: Please elaborate. What goes wrong? Show your code to begin with. Use File.exists() to check if the file exists before you try to read it.

Comment: Please review my updated code

Comment: Let your app create a file in that directory first. Then list again.

Comment: I added the files through file explorer. And i needed to use the folder of images for unit testing

Comment: Yes i knew that your app did not create te file that you are after.